# How to adjust the size of each column in datatable?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatable

I use this script for datatable in laravel 5. I had using class col-lg-4 to adjust the table comlumn, but it was ignored when i am using datatable to the dataset.

The datatable view is like this:
[image: datatable view]

How to adjust the size of each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css grid doesn't affect the column's width of the data table. You can manually pass the width to the data table configuration for each column some thing like this.

```
 $('#mytable').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
     { "width": "10%" },
     { "width": "10%" },
     { "width": "20%" },
     { "width": "30%" },
     { "width": "20%" },
  ]
});
```

For more information, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Comment: Yes, your answer works as it is..Thanks for your help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use columns.width function in javascript.
for more details visit : https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width